# Diavolo and the Requiem Arrow

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I have been watching a lot of *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind* moments on YouTube, and while watching, I thought about Diavolo.

We all know that the main villain of the part got a catastrophic fate. So, if Diavolo has to die infinitely following infinite scenarios, does it mean that in one of these scenarios, he obtains the arrow and pierces himself with it?

My point is that in one of these infinite deaths, he gets King Crimson Requiem and shapes it to be like a direct GER counter or something and thus escapes his horrific punishment.

Answer (score 1):

This answer includes some spoilers for the [JORGE JOESTAR](https://jojowiki.com/JORGE_JOESTAR_(Novel)) novel by Otaro Maijo (**may or may not be considered canon**).

---

In JORGE JOESTAR, Diavolo goes through something similar: After many incarnations, he ends up on a universe where instead of Vinegar Doppio his alternate personality is Giorno Giovanna with Golden Experience Requiem. He cancels his own death and and continues to live ¹. On paper, *yes*, he can escape it.

But when you look at what the Golden Experience Requiem's true power is, it is not the death loop. It is the ability to prevent something becoming a reality. It prevents that reality and creates a new "truth" ². So again, on paper, *no*. It should always be able to create a truth where Diavolo can't escape his punishment.

Golden Experience Requiem isn't clearly explained, even Giorno doesn't know ³. Any definite answer will be opinion-based, unfortunately.

---

References:

¹ https://jojowiki.com/Diavolo/History#JORGE_JOESTAR

² ³ Golden Wind: Chapters 148 and 149